# Show prices including and excluding tax on product information's Price set up in backend

Tags: product, price, tax, backend

Is it possible to show both prices (incl. and excl. tax) in product information part of the backend. I mean the Price tab of the product information.

Answer (score 1):

It already works that way. Magento shows both the price you entered and the amount of VAT/tax added

[image]

Comment: This was not what I meant. I don't need the amount of tax but the price with and without the tax to be shown in backend.